# Create NodeJS (SvelteKit) app with Prisma client included

Tags: node.js, build, prisma, sveltekit

Hey I'm currently building a survey app that clients can host in their own network to give feedback on video research and trainings.

I have a SvelteKit SSR application with Prisma and SQLite as the database. I tried a lot of things to create a single executable file from the app, but there always seems to be a problem. Now I wanted to just try running it with node.
So I use adapter node and `npm run build` to create the app. Now when I run `npm run preview` it all works fine, but it also accesses the dev database file.

When I run `node index.js` (in the ./build dir) It starts the server, I can navigate between pages but I cannot make any changes to the data. Nothing happens

When I create an executable file it also works but it accesses my dev database file.

So my question is, how can I somehow include the sqlite database and prisma client into the build output, so I get a folder with all my files that I need and only need to download node to run it with `node index.js`

I tried, creating a separate database.db file in the build folder, the same location as in the the project source, and also running `npx prisma create` in the build output.
But nothing helped.

Can anyone help me how to create a single nodejs app with all the prisma dependencies. If you also happen to know how I can make an executable from that, I will love you forever.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you find an answer to this? if so please answer your own question and it will be very helpful to the community